# Python for the image denoising using tikhonov regularization

Tags: python, image-processing

What is the error in the code? As it always runs with the error of dimension mismatch

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
def psnr_fun(image1, image2):
    mse = np.mean((image1 - image2) ** 2)
    if mse == 0:
        return float('inf')
    max_pixel = np.max(image1)
    psnr = 20 * np.log10(max_pixel / np.sqrt(mse))
    return psnr

def DiffOper(N):
    data = [-np.ones(N), np.ones(N)]
    offsets = [0, 1]
    D = sp.diags(data, offsets, shape=(N, N+1), format='csc')
    D[0, 0] = 0
    return D
```

Continue the above code. I am using the gradient descent to minimize the tikhonov regularization

```
def tikhonov_gd(y, mu, lamda, nit, tol, n):
    x = y.copy()
    D = DiffOper(int(np.sqrt(n)))
    RelErr = np.zeros(nit)

    for k in range(nit):
        x_old = x.copy()
        r = y - D @ x
        z = D.T @ r
        x = x + mu * (lamda * z - r)

        RelErr[k] = np.linalg.norm(x - x_old, 'fro') / np.linalg.norm(x, 'fro')

        if RelErr[k] < tol:
            RelErr = RelErr[:k+1]
            break

    return x, RelErr
```

Main code
In this part, I run separately and found that here was raising the error of mismatch dimension,but when I run in Matlab and it doesn't cause any error

File "C:\Users\angel\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse_base.py", line 559, in _mul_dispatch
raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')

ValueError: dimension mismatch

```
N = 256
n = N * N
x = np.random.random(n)  # Example data
sigma = 0.09
y = x + sigma * np.max(x) * np.random.randn(n)

mu = 0.05
nit = 1000
tol = 1e-10
lamda = 1
v, Err = tikhonov_gd(y, mu, lamda, nit, tol, n)
```

Continue the above main code part
I display the figure

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

plt.subplot(221)
plt.imshow(x.reshape(N, N), cmap='gray')
plt.axis('image')
plt.title('Original')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(y.reshape(N, N), cmap='gray')
plt.axis('image')
plt.title('Noisy')

plt.subplot(223)
plt.imshow(v.reshape(N, N), cmap='gray')
plt.axis('image')
psnr = psnr_fun(v, x)
plt.title(f'Tikhonov (PSNR = {psnr:.3f} dB)')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.semilogy(Err, linewidth=2.5, color='black')
plt.xlabel('Iterations (k)', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Relative Error', fontsize=12)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(['Gradient Descent'], loc='best', fontsize=12)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and copy-paste the full error message. It has important information that point towards what the problem is. Paraphrasing an error message is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can identify two possible causes for this mismatch:

1. The DiffOper function returns an array D with a shape of (N, N+1). This cannot be [matrix-multiplied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#:%7E:text=For%20matrix%20multiplication%2C%20the%20number,B%20is%20denoted%20as%20AB.) to a matrix x with dimension (N, N) (number of columns in D (N+1) are not equal to the number of rows (N) in x).
2. The random and randn functions of numpy return a 1d array when only providing a single argument to them. In order to get matrices, either the array has to be reshaped ([random](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.random.html)) or more arguments have to be provided ([randn](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randn.html)).

I have implemented these changes into you code (FIX 1-3), but you have to decide whether this still follows your desired logic (especialls with the reduced shape in the sparse matrix).

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp

def DiffOper(N):
    data = [-np.ones(N), np.ones(N)]
    offsets = [0, 1]
    # FIX 1: use shape (N, N) instead of shape (N, N+1)
    D = sp.diags(data, offsets, shape=(N, N), format="csc")
    D[0, 0] = 0
    return D


def tikhonov_gd(y, mu, lamda, nit, tol, n):
    x = y.copy()
    D = DiffOper(int(np.sqrt(n)))
    RelErr = np.zeros(nit)

    for k in range(nit):
        x_old = x.copy()
        r = y - D @ x
        z = D.T @ r
        x = x + mu * (lamda * z - r)

        RelErr[k] = np.linalg.norm(x - x_old, "fro") / np.linalg.norm(x, "fro")

        if RelErr[k] < tol:
            RelErr = RelErr[: k + 1]
            break

    return x, RelErr


N = 256
n = N * N
# FIX 2: reshape into NxN matrix
x = np.random.random(n).reshape((N, N))  # Example data
sigma = 0.09
# FIX 3: directly create an NxN matrix
y = x + sigma * np.max(x) * np.random.randn(N, N)

mu = 0.05
nit = 1000
tol = 1e-10
lamda = 1
v, Err = tikhonov_gd(y, mu, lamda, nit, tol, n)
```

Comment: @Elfs Great! Please mark this answer as "accepted" (green checkmark on the left of this answer) so that it is clear that you question has been answered satisfactorily.